# Add a custom view to the UIViewController from the custom view class

Tags: ios, swift, custom-view

I have a custom view. I named `AnimatingView`. I have customized the view in the `AnimatingView.swift`. In the ViewController, I am initiating the view with

```
let customAnimatingView = AnimatingView(overView: self.view)
```

and then I add the subView with -

```
self.view.addSubview(customAnimatingView)
```

However, I don't want the user add it as a subView like above, rather. I want to call a func from `AnimatingView` and the custom view should add it the controller like -

`customAnimatingView.preset()`

Can anyone give me some hint on how can I achieve such behavior.

Comment: search containerView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the custom view do

```
// add a property that refers to the the vc container of the view
// init it when you create an instance of the view
weak var parentController:UIViewController?
func present() { 
  parentController?.view.addSubview(self)
}
```

OR if you need to send the main view instead

```
var parentView:UIView?
func present() { 
  parentView?.addSubview(self)
}
```

Comment: I actually thought of it. However, I am afraid of generating a retain circle because my custom view is actually a progressView. I am scared that in the completion handler, my reference to the controller might create a retain circle.

Comment: that's way i added `weak` in property and use `[weak self]` in completion